# Feature Request: Display Users Open Questions?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I have asked over 300 questions on the main site; however, for various I have failed to accept an answer for all of them. I would like to clean up my record, but when I wanted to filter my questions based on "open questions" I was disappointed to find this feature nonexistent.

Accepting answers is important for the organization of the site. I believe that implementing this harmless feature will encourage and assist users in accepting answers to their old questions.

Answer (score 7):

If you are only looking for questions of yours that have no accepted answer you can use the search [`user:me hasaccepted:no`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0). To get a list of your questions with no accepted answer but at least one answer posted use [`user:me hasaccepted:no answers:1`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1). (Details about these and many more search parameters can be found in the [How do I search?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) page in the Help Center.)